# Any side effects from this Python logging code?

Tags: python, logging

```
def _getCallerLogger():
    caller = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back
    name = "{}-{}".format(caller.f_globals['__name__'], caller.f_code.co_name )
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    return logger

log = lambda msg : _getCallerLogger().debug(msg)
info = lambda msg: _getCallerLogger().info(msg)
warning = lambda msg: _getCallerLogger().warning(msg)
error = lambda msg: _getCallerLogger().error(msg)
critical = lambda msg: _getCallerLogger().critical(msg)
```

I have the above logging code in my application so I can just call `log` from anywhere and it will print the file and where the log method was called from.

Would there be anything wrong with this in the long run?

Comment: why not `log = _getCallerLogger().debug`? why dont' you set the logger in a variable instead of creating a new one 5 times?

Comment: :) Might have over thought it on the day

Comment: Well that also wouldn't work because I call these methods from all over the code base and in that case _getCallerLogger() would only be called once.

Answer (score 3):

The logging module already supplies a function name to log messages.  If you want to include the function name in your log message just set the appropriate formatter with `%(funcName)s` in the format string on your log handler with: http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.setFormatter

See also http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

The typical usage is to create a global `log` variable in your module like

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and use that logger within functions in that module.  But creating a separate logger for every single function is excessive.

I (just now) realized this is a pretty old question, but if you're still interested I can provide a full working example.